# no return data from Web Method Web Service

Tags: c#, sql

I have a method that is a search for Branches. the parameter is Branch Code and it should return the details of the branch

```
 public bool SearchBranch()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBReader"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Reader.usp_SearchBranch", con))
            {
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.Add("@BranchCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.BranchCode;

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    this.BranchName = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    this.AreaCode = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    this.RegionCode = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    this.CompanyCode = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    this.CompanyName = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code in my Web Method in my Web Service (I dont know if this is correct)

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Search Affected User from Database in Access Request")]
     public bool SearchBranchAccessRequest(AccessRequest accessrequest)
  {
      return accessrequest.SearchBranch();
  }
```

And this is how I access/call  the web method in my web page

```
  protected void SearchBranchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            accessrequest.BranchCode = Convert.ToInt32(BranchCodeTextBox.Text);
            iTicketWebService.SearchBranchAccessRequest(accessrequest);

            if (iTicketWebService.SearchBranchAccessRequest(accessrequest) == true)
            {
                BranchNameLabel.Text = accessrequest.BranchName;
                AreaLabel.Text = accessrequest.AreaCode;
                RegionLabel.Text = accessrequest.RegionCode;
                CompanyCodeLabel.Text = accessrequest.CompanyCode;
                CompanyLabel.Text = accessrequest.CompanyName;
                BranchEmailLabel.Text = accessrequest.BranchCode + "@pjlhuillier.com";
            }
            else
            {
                this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Record not found. Please try again');</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Wrong Input. Please try again');</script>");

        }
    }
```

Help! it doesnt return Branch Name,Area Code,Region Code,Company Code and Company name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your web method as below

```
public AccessRequest SearchBranchAccessRequest(AccessRequest accessrequest)
{
    return accessrequest.SearchBranch(accessrequest);
}
```

and you need to change `SearchBranch()` method as well

```
public accessrequest SearchBranch(AccessRequest accessrequest)
{

    if(you found record in database)
    {
       // update accessrequest here 
    }else
    {
      accessrequest =null;
    }
    // finally return the object
    return accessrequest;
}
```

when you call this web service

```
AccessRequest  request = iTicketWebService.SearchBranchAccessRequest(accessrequest);

if(request!=null)
{
    BranchNameLabel.Text = request.BranchName;
}
```

since your method signature change with above implementation, in case of null object return you can consider it as `false` case as your current implementation and if object return from the service you can consider it as `true` case.

If you need return `true` `false` from the service method and also need to have the updated object then you can have custom class to return both, like below

```
public class SearchBrancResponse
{
    public bool SearchStatus { get; set; }
    public AccessRequest  AccessReq  { get; set; }
}
```

you can then return above from the service method. from client side you have both `Boolean` value and the `AccessRequest`

Comment: it would conflict to my Method (SearchBranch) as it returns true and false.